# Azure Blob Trigger in TypeScript doesn't trigger in deploy

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, azure, azure-functions

I have tested my Azure function to run locally and it works normally but after I deployed, it doesn't trigger whenever I upload a file in the video-temp container.

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myBlob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "video-temp/{name}",
      "connection": "NewContainer"
    }
  ],
  "scriptFile": "../dist/VideoConversionTrigger/index.js"
}
```

this is my `local.settings.json`

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "NewContainer": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https; ..."
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you set `AicquireNewContainer` in application setting?

Comment: yeah. i didn't knew about that and i just added that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

local.settings.json is only used on local. You need to add settings here after deploy:

[image]

And for the error, `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Requested value 'GET,HEAD,DELETE,MERGE,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,PATCH' was not found.`, you can break up the values into separate CORS entries.

Comment: All I need to do is just copy my "AicquireNewContainer" to the settings right?

Comment: @gwynncausing yes

Comment: for no reason my system didn't work, I cannot do any requests

Comment: @gwynncausing what about deploy to a new one? And then add the settings again.

Comment: i tried to reupload all my files again using the AzureWebJobsStorage because it is somehow the same as the one i created. here is the current error

`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Requested value 'GET,HEAD,DELETE,MERGE,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,PATCH' was not found.`

Comment: ohh nevermind. I just solved it through this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/440)

Comment: @gwynncausing So the problem is CORS? How do you solved the problem, can you share?:)

Comment: yeah. it was the CORS, I just separated the values just like what I stated in the issue given before. Thanks man.

Comment: @gwynncausing Thanks for sharing. I have updated my answer. Maybe you can [accept the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwUke.png) to end this question? It will help others who meet the similar problem.:)

Comment: Sure. Thanks for informing me :) I'm too new in this forum.